# TFS - Souce Code Not Matching

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

I am working with another developer using TFS.

When I first pulled the source code the solution would not build on my machine. I managed to fix it by applying a number of updates using Nuget.

It's a c#.net MVC web application.

On my machine the modal popups work correctly but the developer at the other end is saying that they are not working on their machine.

I have made sure I have pushed all my changes and the developer at the other end is saying that have done a recursive pull. So, surely, we have the same code?

Can anyone suggest why the developer at the other end is not seeing the modals?

I suspect it's something to do with nugget packages but I could be wrong?

Can anyone give me any pointers where to look for this problem?

Comment: Modals? Do you mean projects, packages, ...? Also, the title seems unrelated to the question.

Comment: What are the modal popups you're referring to? And are you using git (it seems like it, but I just want to check)

Answer (score 0):

First 'enable nuget package restore' for your solution by right clicking on solution file from Visual Studio and select that option. So that the nuget packages will be downloaded to the solution on build.

Regarding the missing modal please ensure that the packages.config file is also committed/checked in since only the packages listed in the file only be installed to the project.

If possible to come up with the error that would be helpful to find.

Comment: it was already enabled my end. I am asking the other developer to check... and give me any error messages she is seeing

Comment: Does the other developer is able to build successfully? If yes then ask to clear cache and load the page.